# Apply target to cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column (G) in my excel sheet that has a drop down list using data validation. I want to be able to choose multiple options from this list. I copied and used the code from this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHxzDnCQlx4)

```
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$A$10" Or Target.Address = "$D$10" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

As is in the video, the line that would need changing is:

```
If Target.Address = "$A$10" Or Target.Address = "$D$10" Then
```

The code works fine when I apply it to say $G$300, but need to apply it to all of column G *except G1 and G2* and can't seem to work out how to do that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("G3:G" & Rows.Count)) Is Nothing) Then
```